# Variable assignment in if statement

Tags: javascript, swift

In Swift we can assign a variable as we evaluate the existence of a potential value, such as:

```
if let x = y {
  // do something with x
}
```

Is there an equivalent in JavaScript?

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: Even in swift this is bad practice. There's no reason `x` is a different name. Should just be `if let y = y {`

Comment: I think it should be something like this `var y = (y === null || y ===undefined) ? 3 : y`  3 is my default value.

Comment: @FlyingGambit This isn't what that code does.

Comment: I very much disagree that this is bad practice. I think the example is just not clear. For example in swift you could do `} else if let x = resultOfSomeFunction() { ... }` and then use `x` inside that scope. But I don't believe there's a JS equivalent so you just have to calculate it before hand. Not the end of the world, just not as clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such equivalent solution in JavaScript, because there's no equivalent problem.

What you're demonstrating is *conditional binding*, which exists to allow you to create a non-optional value (`x`, in your example), out of an optional value (`y`). There's no such need in Javascript, because all values are nullable, for better or for worse.

You just do a `null` check, like so:

```
if (y) {

}
```

Just as how you shouldn't write JavaScript code in Swift, you shouldn't write Swift code in JavaScript. It's a completely different languages, with completely different features, syntax, patterns and designs.